# Terminology for function interface/DLL used only to fix parameter types between different languages?

Tags: dll, shared-libraries, terminology, language-binding

I have several cases where I needed to make an interface library somewhat "dummy", meaning that it is just needed to make an application written in language A call a library written in language B, in order to fix data types and other small details, without adding functionalities.
Something like this:

Application in language A => **Interface library** => library in language B.

For example I had a case where A was Visual Basic, B was C#, and "interface library" written in Visual Basic.
Another case where A was LabView, B was C, and "interface library" written in C.

I don't remember if there is a standard name to call such an interface library in English language, I mean something like "shell library" or "dummy shell library", etc.
Any suggestion, even if not "standard", is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some of the terms used for mapping between two languages or APIs

- [language binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_binding)
- [glue code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glue_code)
- [foreign function interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_function_interface)
- [wrapper library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapper_library)
- [adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern)

Personally, I often use the term *glue code* which wikipedia defines as

> ...code that serves solely to "adapt" different parts
>   of code that would otherwise be incompatible. Glue code does not
>   contribute any functionality towards meeting program requirements.
>   Instead, it often appears in code that lets existing libraries or
>   programs interoperate,...